# What are all these Graves for?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

Every time I make Homer raid a random fridge for a quest, I end up getting another open grave. They don't appear to give me any bonuses or money or xp or anything.

Do they have a purpose, or are they just cluttering up my town?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that they *may* improve your Vanity rating, as other decorations that serve no other purpose typically do -- however in this case I don't believe it does.

The longer answer is that they were a limited-time episode tie-in item, playing on the premise of Homer's almost-unlimited clone lives and the many, many deaths (and associated funerals) he experienced during the episode.

You're not losing out on anything by not placing them in your Springfield. On the other hand, who wouldn't want a large cemetery full of Homer coffins?